# Workflow info from Oozie through Java API call

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I want to develop a Java API to connect with Oozie to get the workflow information. My requirement is I will be passing the workflow name as the input and it should list all the job Ids (with status as running, killed, failed etc) and other related info.

I am trying to use this function to get this details.

```
String wfname="test";
List<WorkflowJob> jobinfo = wc.getJobsInfo(wfname,0,2);
```

However I am getting an error when I execute the jar:

```
Invalid jobs filter [test], elements must be semicolon-separated name=value pairs.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for filter for the **getJobsInfo(String)**, **getJobsInfo(String, int, int)** methods is :

```
 [NAME=VALUE][;NAME=VALUE]*.
```

Error itself says that you are not using name=value pairs

> elements must be semicolon-separated name=value pairs

Try something like following :  `name=testwf1;name=testwf2`

Please refer the [OozieClient](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/client/apidocs/org/apache/oozie/client/OozieClient.html) for more details.